# RHEL 6 HP Tape Driver Installation Troubles

Tags: linux, drivers, redhat-enterprise-linux

Trying to install tape drive drivers for the HP Ultrium 3280 SAS using this guide

http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02262008.pdf

Whenever, I try to execute `mkltfs` I get this error

> mkltfs: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.48: cannot
>   open shared object file: No such file or directory

I messed with shared libraries for a while, trying to add folder containing `libicui18n.so.48` to LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable but it does not seem to work.

I worked with linux before but can not figure this one out. Any suggestions or pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Usually LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the user running the commands will fix the problem.  However, since you're on RHEL, you can do the following:

If your system, like RHEL 6, has a directory called /etc/ld.so.conf.d, create a new file called hp-tape which contains the full path (no trailing '/', and no file names) to where your libicui18n.so.48 is.

After adding that file (as root), run ldconfig.  That will add the new configuration to the sysem library paths, and every user and every command execution environment will be able to see those libraries.

If you only have a configuration file /etc/ld.so.conf then add the path (again, no trailing slash, no file name) to that file and run ldconfig.